# Longest path regex match

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am working on a [MQTT handler](https://github.com/jsdario/replyer) for which I want to emit an event for the longest event name matching. Example:

I am listening for several events:

- `test`
- `test/replyer/`
- `test/replyer/request`

And I am going to receive a message with a topic like `test/replyer/request/@issuer` which should trigger the event `test/replyer/request`.

Is any regexp strategy that can help me out to find which is the largest matching path in javascript?

**EDIT:**

`test`, `replyer` and `request` are arbitrary strings for the example. The event list above can be anything that can appear on a path. The path length is also unknown.

Comment: How many events are you listening to? Can you give a complete list?

Comment: I just edited – there is an arbitrary number of events. All events can be described as paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the events you are listening to, you can use this regex:

```
/test\/(?:replyer\/(?:request\/)?)?/
```

[regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/bE5gS5/1)

If the events can be anything and should be extracted from a URL, then your question really is to find the path part of a URL in general:

```
/.*?(?=\/[^\/]*$)/
```

[regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7xC3/1)

JavaScript function:

```js
function eventFromUrl(url) {
  return (url.match(/.*?(?=\/[^\/]*$)/) || []).pop();
}
var url = 'test/replyer/request/@issuer';
document.write(eventFromUrl(url));
```

If you have a list of allowable events (paths), then you could use the above and chop of from the path until you have one that is in the list:

```js
function eventFromUrl(url) {
  return (url.match(/.*?(?=\/[^\/]*$)/) || []).pop();
}
var validEvents = {
  'test/replyer': 1,
  'test/replyer/request': 1,
  'test': 1,
  'test/requester': 1,
  'test/requester/request': 1,
  'test/replyer/report': 1,
};
var url = 'test/replyer/request/@issuer';
for (var event = url; event && !validEvents[event]; event = eventFromUrl(event));
document.write (event);
```

Comment: `test`, `replyer` and `request` are arbitrary strings for the example. They can be anything that can appear on a normal URL. How can we edit this to turn it into the generic regex that solves the problem?

Comment: So do I understand correctly, that given any URL you want to take out the last part? I have added this to my answer.

Comment: Added the solution for when you have a closed list of events to test against. The longest will be found by taking out parts from the URL until it matches.